# If F = F1+F2 is some measured random field, how to find out if F2 has been correctly estimated and subtracted?

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation

I have a random field, F, defined on the surface of a sphere pixellized into about a million points. I know that F must consist of two components - F1 and F2, F1 being a true signal and F2 being some contaminant. They cannot be measured independently but it is known that they should be completely uncorrelated to each other. F2 is estimated using some theoretical method and subtracted from F to leave behind F1. My question is: how can I check whether there is any residual contaminant left behind in F1 ? What would be a good statistical to do this check ? Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: What is the model? Usually there are assumptions, i.e. properties of F2 or F1 which you can check. Failure to have these properties may lead to conclusion that the contamination is not eradicated. Without more details I doubt that anyone could give you more precise answer.

Comment: Another approach is to estimate the optimality of your method via the variance of the estimator under e.g. bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly, you can't.  If your method of subtracting F2 is optimal, then anything you could identify as potentially contaminant would already be subtracted off.

You can always do things like check the goodness of fit of the F1 and F2 that you calculate to the models that you think they should fit, but that's not really the same thing.